# In C#/XAML/WPF, how do I make a button appear only if another button is clicked?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, windows-8

I was wondering how to do this. I am trying to learn how to make a Metro-style app for Windows Store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Attach an `Click` event to the source button
2. In event handler mark `button2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;'

As simple as that.